# DynamoDB returns 200 statusCode for deleteItem but it still exists on the console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My table has a hash key `userId` (there is no range key).

I am calling the API as follows (from Node.js):

```js
dynamo.deleteItem({
    "TableName": 'my-table', 
    "Key": {
        "userId": '4ada7bbd-a8ac-4d29-94c6-e199a50430c9'
    }
}
```

I am calling this API and it is returning statusCode of 200 successful, but that item still exists on the DynamoDB console even if I refreshed with the refresh button.

How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you could post some details? Such as the code you use to delete, the name of the partition key and sort key, maybe a screenshot of the console, etc.

Comment: @AugustLilleaas added the details

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that the `DeleteItem` operation succeeds even if you delete a non-existing item. In your case, probably an item with the key "4ada7bbd-a8ac-4d29-94c6-e199a50430c9" doesn't exist - maybe there is some typo in the name or something?

Try using `GetItem` to get the item instead of `DeleteItem` - then you'll be able to verify that the item that you think exists with this key, doesn't exist. Or, use `GetItem` **after** the `DeleteItem` to verify in that way that the item is gone after the delete. Don't mix code and UI in the same test because it's harder to know what you did wrong if you can't paste a stand-alone failing code.